# Where does the verse "aavaahanan na jaanaami..." come from?

Tags: mantras, shloka, puja, reference-request

Whenever a pooja is completed in my home, my mother says this.

> आवाहनं न जानामि न जानामि तवार्चनम्।
> पूजां श्चैव न जानामि क्षम्यतां परमेश्वर॥

Where does this verse come from?

Comment: From Kshama prarthana, said at the end of devi mahatmyam.

Comment: न - No जानामि - Know आवाहनं - invite तवार्चनम् - your archana पूजां - puja श्चैव - too क्षम्यतां - forgive परमेश्वर - Shiva Can you understand meaning now ?

Answer (score 1):

It's in a lot of places- one of them is the [Rudrashtadhyayi](https://shribaglamukhi.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/rudrashtadhyayi-hindibook-pdf.pdf), which originates from the Shukla Yajur Veda.

> आवाहनं न जानामि न जानामि तवार्चनम् ।
> पूजां चैव न जानामि क्षमस्व परमेश्वर ॥ २
>
> *aavaahanan na jaanaami na jaanaami tavaarchanam
>
> poojaan chaiv na jaanaami kshamasv bhagavaan*